# (Rad studio c++) How should I use TImage->LoadFromFile() if my target platform is android?

Tags: android, firemonkey

I want to load png files which are not on my android device but on my Windows device to TImage,what should I do or what path should I put in the function TImage->LoadFromFile()?

Comment: I doubt your Android device can see your Windows file system as is. You need to have the windows folder shared... then you have to mount the window share on Android (there are some apps that allow you to do this)... and then you should be able to access it as a file. The actual path will depend on how you set all of this up. But all this will work only when the two devices are somehow networked and the file system is mounted... which needs to be done every time you turn them on.

Comment: Thanks for help,Frazz
Another question:Can I package my image to apk file?(I'm a freshman of managing project so my question will be silly,sorry)

Comment: AFAIK you should be able to include resource files in the Android apk. I haven't done this myself (yet), but I think I saw some reference in the Embarcadero documentation... and certainly you can find similar questions here on SO. If not, post another question, but please do include what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You did not explain very well what you want, but if you want the user select the image, you can do this easily using TActionList:

1) Add the TACtionList to the form;
2) Add the uses "FMX.ActnList, FMX.StdActns, FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions";
3) Right click in ActionList1 component >> "Action List Editor..." >> Ctrl + Ins >> Select the TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction;
4) Use the event OnDidFinishTaking of the TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction to get the TBitmap;
5) Link an button of the form to the TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction;

---

If you want to load an image in app folder you need to add it to deployment (Delphi >> Project >> Deployment) with the remote path "./assets/internal". Then you can load it using the:
 Image1.bitmap.LoadFromFile(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Image.png'));